# Is it right to call a job which has begun to bore you a "plain" job?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

What is the best english adjective to identify a job in which you always do the same things over and over and so eventually get bored from it?

I read somewhere the sentence "I have a plain job", "I am doing a plain work"...do these sentences mean what I am searching for?

Or is there another better adjective? I don't like "boring" because it already identifies your final state, after you have experience in the job. Maybe at the start you found it amazing because it is something new...so I think "boring" is not the best word.

edit: maybe "static" would do?

Comment: Tedious, unexciting, uninteresting, repetitive, monotonous, dull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you felt you were getting nothing out of the job, you could describe it as being **uninspiring**. If the work itself was so repetitive that it was making you bored of it maybe you could describe it as being **tedious**.

Answer (score 2):

**Menial**

Merriam Webster's second definition

- **menial**: used to describe boring or unpleasant work that does not require special skill and usually does not pay much money

A job could be menial.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a lot of it around.

**mundane** [Google Dictionary]:

> adjective 1.
>
> lacking interest or excitement; dull.
>
> "his mundane, humdrum existence"
>
> synonyms: humdrum, dull, boring, tedious, monotonous, tiresome,
>   wearisome, prosaic, unexciting, uninteresting, uneventful, unvarying,
>   unvaried, unremarkable, repetitive, repetitious, routine, ordinary,
>   everyday, day-to-day, quotidian, run-of-the-mill, commonplace, common,
>   workaday, usual, pedestrian, customary, regular, normal;

Answer (score 1):

Consider **uninteresting,** it describes the task rather than your reaction to the task.  The task cannot generate or sustain a worker's enthusiasm.

Comment: It is the same of "boring": maybe at the start you find it interesting because it is something new. But doing it for months will make it boring.

Comment: We must distinguish the task from your reaction to it.  The task may be intrinsically dull from the start, but you only realize it much later.